# play mp3 file in background while running javafx application

Tags: java, javafx

I am making javafx cinema seat reservation system as semester project.I want to add .mp3 music so that it plays in background while application is running and performing its fuctions.I added music but what happens is when I run code applications starts and I can perform my seat selections in GUI but there is no background music.but when I click cross(close button) GUI closes and music starts playing...I only included the music code portion.have a look

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
public class Cinemafx extends Application{
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("song.mp3");
            Player player = new Player(fileInputStream);
            System.out.println("Song is playing...");
            player.play();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);


    }


}
```

Comment: What is `Player`? And JavaFX has its own media API: [`javafx.media`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.media/module-summary.html).

Comment: There is no `Player` class in the JavaFX library itself. Furthermore the way you set up your stage(s) may be important. Please provide a [mcve] in the question.